# How to filter rows with non Latin characters

Tags: python, pandas

I am stuck in a problem with a dataframe with a column of film names which has a bunch of non-latin names like Japanese or Chinese (and maybe Russian names too) my code is:

```
df['title'].head(5)
```

1 I am legend 
2 wonder women 
3 アライヴ 
4 怪獣総進撃 
5 dead sea

I just want an output that removes every non-Latin character title, so I want to remove every row that contains character similar to row 3 and 4, so my desired output is:

```
df['title'].head(5)
```

1 I am legend 
2 wonder women 
5 dead sea 
6 the rig 
7 altitude

Any help with this code?

Comment: Are you allowing ASCII only latin letters, or are latin letters not present in ASCII allowed, for example ñ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.match` with the Latin character range to identify non-latin characters, and use the boolean output to slice the data:

```
df_latin = df[~df['title'].str.match(r'.*[^\x00-\xFF]')]
```

output:

```
          title
1   I am legend
2  wonder women
5      dead sea
6       the rig
7      altitude
```

Comment: I think you should change `7F` to `FF` *non-latin character title*?

Answer (score 1):

You can encode your title column then decode to `latin1`. If this double transformation does not match your original data, remove row because it contains some non Latin characters:

```
df = df[df['title'] == df['title'].str.encode('unicode_escape').str.decode('latin1')]
print(df)

# Output
          title
0   I am legend
1  wonder women
3      dead sea
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`isascii()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isascii) method (if you're using Python 3.7+). Example:

```
"I am legend".isascii()  # True
"アライヴ".isascii()  # False
```

Even if you have 1 Non-English letter, the `isascii()` method will return `False`.

(Note that for strings like `'34?#5'` the method will return `True`, because those are all ASCII characters.)

Answer (score 0):

We can easily makes a function which will return whether it is ascii or not and based on that we can then filter our dataframe.

```
dict_1 = {'col1':list(range(1,6)), 'col2':['I am legend','wonder women','アライヴ','怪獣総進撃','dead sea']}

def check_ascii(string):
    if string.isascii() == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)
df['is_eng'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: check_ascii(x))
df2 = df[df['is_eng'] == True]
df2
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIf4B.png)

Comment: Could replace `lambda x: check_ascii(x)` with simply `str.isascii` and not define `check_ascii` at all.